# bot.command won't work no matter how much I try (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot, I have been able to make it respond to message events, but I can't get to make the commands work, I tried almost every solution I could see on stack.
I do get the error stating

```
Unused import statement 'import discord':2
```

Here's the code-

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('yo'):
        await message.channel.send('yo momma is fat')

bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `pass_context=True`, this is very old, not sure where you got that from, also, import discord before discord.ext (just for formatting)